# Calculating Confusion Matrix by Using the Array of Arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I am using transformers and datasets libraries to train an multi-class nlp model for real specific dataset and I need to have an idea how my model performs for each label. So, I'd like to calculate the confusion matrix. I have 4 labels. My `result.prediction` looks like

```
array([[ -6.906 ,  -8.11  , -10.29  ,   6.242 ],
       [ -4.51  ,   3.705 ,  -9.76  ,  -7.49  ],
       [ -6.734 ,   3.36  , -10.27  ,  -6.883 ],
       ...,
       [  8.41  ,  -9.43  ,  -9.45  ,  -8.6   ],
       [  1.3125,  -3.094 , -11.016 ,  -9.31  ],
       [ -7.152 ,  -8.5   ,  -9.13  ,   6.766 ]], dtype=float16)
```

In here when predicted value is positive then model predicts 1, else model predicts 0. Next my `result.label_ids` looks like

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

As you can see model return an array of 4, and give 0 values to false labels and 1 to true values.

In general, I've been using the following function to calculate confusion matrix, but in this case it didn't work since this function is for 1 dimensional arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def compute_confusion_matrix(labels, true, pred):

  K = len(labels) # Number of classes 
  result = np.zeros((K, K))

  for i in range(labels):
    result[true[i]][pred[i]] += 1

  return result
```

If possible I'd like to modify this function suitable for my above case. At least I would like to understand how can I implement confusion matrix for results that in the form multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: Hi! Can you specify if this is a multi-class or multi-label classification problem (in multi-class classification the assumption is that each row of the `numpy` array that you showed will always have a single `1` and three `0`s while in multi-label classification a single row could have more than one `1`). Also having an example of your `labels` and `true` inputs for this instance of the problem could be useful.

Comment: I mentioned at the beginning that this is a multi-class NLP problem with 4 labels. My true inputs are of the form `[0,0,0,1]`. Same as elements of `result.label_ids` above. My labels are one hot encoded. So in my dataset each label has their own column, and they encoded into a list with length 4 as a label vector. Hope this clarify things better :)

Comment: Ok! Just one thing: did you mean to write `for i in range(len(labels))` in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank **Nicola Fanelli** for the idea.

The function I gave above as well as the `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()` both need to be provided a list  of predicted and true values. After my prediction step, I try to retrieve my true and predicted values in order to calculate a confusion matrix. The results I was getting are in the following form

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Here the idea is to retrieve the positional index of the value 1. When I tried the approach suggested by **Nicola Fanelli** , the resulting sizes were lower then the initial ones and they weren't matching. Therefore, confusion matrix cannot be calculated. To be honest I couldn't find the reason behind it, but I'll investigate that more later.

So, I use a different technique to implement the same idea. I used `np.argmax()` and append these positions to a new list. Here is the code sample for true values

```
true = []
for i in range(len(result.label_ids)):
    n = np.array(result.label_ids[i])
    true.append(np.argmax(n))
```

This way I got the results in the desired format without my sizes are being changed.

Even though this is a working solution for my problem, I am still open to more elegant ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility could be reversing the encoding to the format required by `compute_confusion_matrix` and, in this way, it is still possible to use your function!

To convert the predictions it's possible to do:

```py
pred = list(np.where(result.label_ids == 1.)[1])
```

where `np.where(result.label_ids == 1.)[1]` is a `numpy` 1-dimensional array containing the indexes of the `1.`s in each row of `result.label_ids`.

So `pred` will look like this according to your `result.label_ids`:

```py
[3, 0, 3, ..., 0, 0, 3]
```

so it should have the same format of the original `true` (if also `true` is one-hot encoded the same strategy could be used to convert it) and can be used as input of your function for computing the confusion matrix.

Comment: Idea is great. One problem is when i use function np.where() size of result.prediction and result.label_ids are changing. Hence, their size are not matching and the function throws an error. I used same idea and improve it by using np.argmax() function and everything started to work. This way my sizes are still matching and I am still getting the positional values of the largest element. Thanks a lot for the idea :)